# No default constructor for entity for inner class in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, composite-key

I have two classes. One is the entity class, the other serves as a composite key class.

The code is as followed.

```
@Entity
public class Supply {

    @Embeddable
    class Id implements Serializable {

        @Column(name = "supplier_id")
        private long supplierId;
        @Column(name = "merchandise_id")
        private long merchandiseId;

        public Id() {
        }

        public Id(long sId, long mId) {
            this.supplierId = sId;
            this.merchandiseId = mId;
        }
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    private Id id = new Id();
}
```

If I use try to find

```
from Supply where merchandise_id=%d and supplier_id=%d
```

Hibernate will throw an exception,namely:

```
No default constructor for entity: com.entity.Supply$Id; nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity: com.entity.Supply$Id
```

However, I found that if I change *class* **Id** to **static**. Everything will be fine.

I am just curious about how all these stuff can happen.

Comment: It would help a lot if you included the hibernate warning ID "HHH000182" in this posting. The static thing fixed stuff for me, but finding this answer was hard!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If the class is not `static`, it requires an instance of the outer class in order to be instantiated - so there will be no default constructor. You'd have to use syntax similar to:

```
new Supply().new Id();
```

If the `Id` class is `static`, you can just call:

```
new Id();
```

Answer (score 10):

I always add an empty protected constructor to the class to solve this issue like so:

```
protected Classname(){}
```

In your case it would look like this:

```
protected Id(){}
```

Comment: How does this solve the issue?  You still need to have a static class.

Answer (score 0):

If class is non static it will require outer class instance to exist. So, I think, generated constructor in this case will have implicit parameter for outer class.

---

Update

As I expected:

```
$ javap -classpath . Supply\$Id
Compiled from "Supply.java"
class Supply$Id extends java.lang.Object{
    final Supply this$0;
    Supply$Id(Supply);
}
```